# Type definition approach

Tags: rest, api, raml

Suppose that I have a endpoint that support three methods: GET, POST and PUT.

The type that will be returned contais two attributes: an `id` and a `name`. Both are `required`.

My question is about how to define this type in RAML definition, since on `POST`, the `id` should be crated automatically and on `PUT` the `id` will be a `URI` parameter. Do you guys creates two `Types` (one for GET and other for PUT, POST) or uses the same type for all operations, declaring the `id` as not `required`?

Sorry if this appears to be a such basic question, but I searched for this and didn't get any conclusive responses.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can provide an example of how you expect it to work. Also please specify the RAML version you are using (assuming 1.0 for now).

Your endpoint provides a POST. That implies some kind of collection that you can add an item to. Then you can use the GET to retrieve such an item.

- you can create a second endpoint for an item of your collection: you'll end up with a `/collection` (all items) and a `/collection/12345678` (one item alone, specifically, the item with id 12345678)
- or you can use the query string to filter your collection to find that specific item: `/collection?id=12345678` (a subset of the collection that happens to contain one item instead of multiple)

Maybe, you could also look into the use of [*uriParameters*](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#template-uris-and-uri-parameters).

To illustrate:

```
/types:
    myidtype:
        type: string
        pattern: ^[0-9]{8}$
/collection:
    get: # to retrieve the entire collection
        queryParameters: # to be able to filter the collection into a subset of 1 or more items
            id:
                type: myidtype
                required: false
            name:
                type: string
                required: false
    post: # to create a new item and add it to the collection, id and name will go in the body
    /{myId}: # this is one item
        uriParameters:
            myId:
                type: myidtype
        get: # to retrieve all information on this item
        post: # to post some property to this item
```

Please note that my example is not completely correct. It's about the concept rather than the precise syntax.